# key down event of ; are not working in firefox. But, working in chrome

Tags: javascript, key-events

```js
$("body").on("keydown", function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 186) {
    $("#message").html("Pressed ;");
  } else {
    $("#message").html("Not Pressed ;");
  }
})

d3.select("body").on("keydown", function () {
  if (d3.event.keyCode === 186) {
    $("#d3-message").html("D3 - Pressed ;");
  } else {
    $("#d3-message").html("D3 - Not Pressed ;");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

jQuery
<div id="message"></div>

<hr>
D3
<div id="d3-message"></div>
```

I have this kind of a logic in my code, And this is working only in chrome, not in firefox

Other than that need to get this resolved even for D3.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As metal03326 points out, the keycode for `;` is different between Chrome and Firefox. [This page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) contains a breakdown of how different browsers handle keyCodes.

You can get around this by checking the `.key` property instead:

```
$("body").on("keydown", function (evt) {
    if (evt.key === ';') { console.log("pressed ;"); }
})
```

The `.keyCode` property is deprecated and you should not use it. The [MDN page for KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) says as much:

> Warning: This attribute is deprecated; you should use `KeyboardEvent.key` instead, if available.

### Full snippet:

```js
$("body").on("keydown", function (evt) {
  if (evt.key === ';') {
    $("#message").html("Pressed ;");
  } else {
    $("#message").html("Not Pressed ;");
  }
})

d3.select("body").on("keydown", function () {
  if (d3.event.key === ';') {
    $("#d3-message").html("D3 - Pressed ;");
  } else {
    $("#d3-message").html("D3 - Not Pressed ;");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

jQuery
<div id="message"></div>

<hr>
D3
<div id="d3-message"></div>
```

Comment: have they provided any way to trigger events by "evt.key"

Comment: may be using jquery-simulate

Comment: @DinukaDeSilva I don't understand what you're asking. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Is there any alternative for D3.js similar to this

Comment: JLRishe By the way..... your answer is correct..... And I have another two questions  1) whether you know how to test this using jquery-simulate 2) any alternative for d3.js similar to this

Comment: Even in d3.js the same problem is there.... do you know any option for that..... I updated the question

Comment: @DinukaDeSilva As seen in the snippet above `evt.key` works just as well in D3. The event is generated by the browser, not the library. I'm not familiar with jquery-simulate, so can't advise you on that.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, the `;` is with code **59**. You can check it [here](http://keycode.info/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body").on("keydown", function (evt) {
   var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
  if (evt.keyCode === 186 && !isFirefox) {
    $("#message").html("Pressed ;");
  } else if(evt.keyCode === 59 && isFirefox){
    $("#message").html("Pressed ;");
  }else {
    $("#message").html("not Pressed ;");
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="message"></div>
```